Cashless visit to Schengen countries using USA credit card
How is the cashless situation in Schengen, particularly the Northern and Eastern Europe countries, for American visitors using a US credit card? I heard Amex coverage is spotty but Visa/Mastercard coverage should be decent for those that accept it. Also heard recommendations to add the credit card to Google/Apple Pay since EU uses pins for credit cards but US credit cards usually don't have them (and are Google/Apple Pay even prevalent enough to matter)?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Looking at the tags of your question, I see Denmark, Germany and Poland. IMO, you can live comfortably without cash in Denmark, but not in Germany and Poland. Apart from big cities, it's easy to come across a place that accepts only cash.
Regarding card types, you might as well leave your AMEX at home. Basically only big hotels consistently accept them. VISA and MasterCard are universally accepted; I can't think of any single card-accepting merchant in Europe who doesn't accept both VISA and MasterCard cards. About 15 years ago, some shops in Germany only accepted German EC-cards (as a big country, they have their own card transaction network), but I don't think that's the case anymore. EDIT: According to local experts, some merchants in Germany still only accept German girocards, which is a new name for former EC-cards.
Contactless payments are ubiquitous. In the countries you mentioned, virtually all terminals accept contactless payments using a card or a phone (GPay, Apple Pay) or a similar device.
Since it's not a good idea to travel completely cashless in those countries, you should have a card that's usable for ATM cash withdrawals (that's easier than exchanging cash). If you only have credit cards, double check the terms and conditions for withdrawing cash, especially in a foreign currency.

I live in Germany and it is still not uncommon that shops only accept German bank cards. FWIW, they are now called girocard and not EC-cards anymore. I live in Germany and my bank stopped issuing girocards last year. I now only have VISA and Mastercard and there are several shops and restaurants I regularly visit here in Munich, where I have to pay cash, since international cards are not accepted.

Germany got a lot more card friendly during/after Covid. I rarely see anywhere that doesn't accept cards where I am in the rural far north although, like Tor-Einar, I still occasionally come across places which only accept girocard.

@JackAidley I am honestly not sure if there are regional differences within Germany, but here in Munich, although it surely improved during covid, there are still plenty of places not accepting cards at all, or also quite comminly, only for payments above a certain threshold, often 10 or 15€. Cheaper restaurants, fast food joints or kiosks are typical locations where card payments are not possible, Taxis in Munich are only since 2022 required to accept card payments, but the card reader is often 'broken'. My butcher (and also often other traditional shops) is also not accepting cards.

I disagree about insufficient support for cards in Poland, despite being a Polish citizen that likes to complain about how behind we're in many areas. As long as you don't use Amex you should be fine - unless you go to the remote villages that to places that only operate without paying taxes. For a few years it's mandatory to electronic payments, so when one does enough business, it just makes no sense not to take cards.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Obviously this varies a lot by country but here is a summary from my latest trips (10+ countries in Europe)

Amex is useless outside the US. Acceptance is low and even if they take it you may have to pay an extra AMEX surcharge.
Visa/Master Card acceptance is very good overall even for small stuff (grocery, convenience store, public transport).
Totally cashless is probably not a good idea. You still run into exceptions and it's not as cashless as say, Australia, New Zealand, or the US
Some exceptions: It's sometimes not possible to tip cashless. Some street vendors do only take cash. A more interesting one: some upscale German restaurants are cash only (you want to watch for that one, since it can be a sizable bill).


I am not sure what countries you have visited, but your first point is factually incorrect for Italy, where I live. I use an AMEX card and 70 to 80% of places accept it, and there is no such thing as an AMEX surcharge, which would be illegal in Italy, and I believe in most of the other EU countries.

See also this question on acceptance in the UK (basically, until you get off the beaten track, it's widely accepted).  Also no AmEx surcharge, which (also) would be illegal.

Your mileage may vary. A hotel in London charged me 3% surcharge for using Amex (over Visa or MC).  This may violate their Amex agreement but they still did it. Many restaurants in London have "No Amex" signs on the door. I was in restaurant on Abby Road where they brought the check out in an Amex credit card holder but refused the Amex card, that I put it. "Sorry no Amex, we just use the holder since we got it for free".

My partner has an Amex, and she uses it for preference here in the UK since it has better rewards than her Visa. Acceptance is unpredictable -- sometimes a restaurant doesn't, sometimes a random coffee stall in a market does. If the cashier isn't the proprietor, often the answer to "do you take Amex" is, "I don't know, try it". Very few places seem to prominently display the logos, like they did in the good old days. I would not go Amex-only in the UK, but if you have it you'll find places to use it. Our experience of Schengen is more limited and touristy, but certainly it's often not usable.

In the Netherlands, most shops won't accept any credit cards at all. And credit cards without chip and PIN are not accepted anywhere. If you don't have a debit card, you're going to have to use ATMs to get cash and those obviously don't accept your signature and a slip.

@jwenting, I would not say most shops, supermarkets in the Netherlands mostly do not take credit cards but Shops where they expect tourists mostly do accept them.

@SteveJessop: That's fair and may have changed over time a bit. My point here is that relaying on Amex as the "only" card is probably not a good choice in Europe. Despite using Amex as their travel provider my employer changed their corporate CC to Visa after everyone bitterly complained about poor international acceptance.

The situation may vary a lot by country.
Here is the situation in France:

It's probably difficult to go completely cashless
Visa/Mastercard support is widespread but not universal (see below), but there are quite a few places with a minimum spend (often somewhere between 5 and 15 euros), especially smaller shops (I'm looking at you, my butcher...). On the other hand most boulangeries and supermarkets will accept cards even for 1 euro.
While France has its own national card system, it has coexisted from the beginning with Visa and Mastercard, so it's nearly unheard of to have a store accepting national cards and not foreign cards (quite different from the situation in the Netherlands for instance).
Contactless coverage is nearly universal for those who accept cards, like above.
Amex: pretty rare, though other than the usual higher-end shops, hotels, restaurants, etc, there are some interesting exceptions (many supermarkets for instance: Monoprix, Carrefour, Cora...). You can use the Amex app to find stores which support it.

A few notes:

Taxis are required by law to accept credit cards, whatever the amount. Still, especially outside Paris, they will often tell you there's a minimum, or that the machine is broken, or whatever. Often easier to use Uber or their competitors, but if you are in a hurry at peak times taxis can use bus lanes while Ubers et al. (officially) cannot.
Cards are less likely to be accepted on food markets, though that varies widely
The authentication method is normally determined by the card/device, but it must be supported. In many cases if your card requires a signature it may indeed be a problem. But while you may not know it, your card is likely to have a PIN, or you can request one.
French-issued cards use a PIN for contact and no PIN for contactless (limited to 50 euros). Some terminals will accept contactless cards beyond 50 euros with a PIN. Contactless cards need to be inserted and use a PIN after a number of contactless transactions (3 I think?).
Apple Pay uses Face ID/Touch ID and there is no standard limit. Probably the same for Google Pay and others.
While there were a few issues with Apple Pay when it started rolling out, it now works very well. Haven't had a problem using it for ages.
Places which require a security deposit (hotels, car or bike rentals...) will usually require a real card.
Make sure you check both transaction fees and currency exchange fees for the card(s) you intend to use. It may be worth it to open an account with Wise or Revolut and get a card from them to avoid/reduce fees.
In some cities (Lyon, Toulouse...) you can pay public transport directly with your card or phone (just tap the card or phone on the dedicated reader -- often not the same one as that used for regular tickets). In others you will have to buy tickets and/or load them on your phone first (Paris, Bordeaux, Reims...). The exact mechanism varies (NFC, QR Code, Bluetooth...).
At some point SNCF (the public railway company) kiosks had trouble with some foreign cards. I hope they fixed it, as it's more and more difficult to buy a ticket from a human. The official app and website (SNCF Connect) can be temperamental.

I have limited recent experience in other Schengen countries (and not at all in many), but:

Again, the situation is likely to vary a lot from country to country
Many countries have a national system, and some merchants will only accept cards using that system. It gets better, but there are many holdouts, and often pretty annoying ones (like public transport companies).
Some countries still have strong cash culture.
Nearly universally, there will be situations where you will need cash, though your experience may vary based on the types of merchants you rely on (mostly large, tourist-oriented or small, local-oriented) and the places you go to (rural locations vs large cities). I'm pretty sure some people are able to do an entire trip without using a cent in cash. But it's easy to stumble on cases where you need cash, especially if you don't have a local card in the countries which favour them.


Contactless cards need to be inserted and use a PIN after a number of contactless transactions (3 I think?). I used mine all the time and it's definitely more than 3, I believe it used to be 5 but it's more flexible now, possibly based on the total amount or some sort of risk assessment? The limit can also be reset by entering the PIN without having to insert the card (that's really new in France and not universal, had seen it in the Netherlands for some time).

This is a very much France based answer, not as the question indicated northern and eastern Europe. Can you edit in details for other countries?

@Willeke I can’t speak about the other countries as I have little experience about them, much less recent experience. I’ll leave that to others who know, though I expect different answers for different countries or groups of countries depending on each answerer’s experience.

@Relaxed I think there’s also a time-based component, something like 3 per day. But since I haven’t used a physical contactless card in a while (I nearly always use Apple Pay) I didn’t really track the related policies.

@jcaron I don't know about the policies either but I can tell you I use my physical card all the time, I am almost certain I did it more then 3 times in a row (say paying drink one by one or at the market).

When I started using a new debit card (from a Dutch bank) I needed to use a terminal with its pin one time to activate the contactless option, I think I had to insert the card but I am not sure about that. The next use was the London Underground and it worked.

@Willeke Indeed many banks have that annoying security feature. For some it's even worse, you need to make a payment with PIN (or a withdrawal in an ATM) before you can use it online. Other banks have a different security procedure to ensure the cardholder is the one who actually received the card, using their app or online banking, that's much more practical IMHO.

SNCF app worked very well with my German credit card two years ago IIRC.

@Relaxed  The number of times and the amount you can pay contactless without PIN entry differ from issuing bank to issuing bank and may also depend on national legislation. There are no global policies. If usage thresholds are exceeded, it is not necessarily required to insert the card, but contactless payments with PIN entry is also an option often used. In addition, also the point of sale may have different or additional restrictions for contactless payments.

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo Sure but that's not really what the discussion was about. The point is that French banks used to have some sort of standard policy they even communicated to the public when they rolled out the technology. Similarly, contactless payment with PIN was just not supported until very recently in France (a few weeks I think), which is why jcaron mentioned “inserting the card” in his answer and people are still visibly surprised that they don't have to do that. Obviously the answer is specifically about France, not global policies.

Something I ran into in McDonalds in france, the automated payment terminal had an english option, but when I got to payment it gave me three options, all of which had names in French and none of which mentioned Visa or Mastercard. I guessed "carte-bancaire", which turned out to be indeed the correct option and accepted my contactless UK card (can't remember if it was my Visa Debit card or my Mastercard credit card).

@PeterGreen IIRC they ask whether you are going to pay by card or at the counter. The latter is required for cash payments or using paper "titres-restaurants". There are card versions of the "titres-restaurants", which may require a specific selection. "Titres-restaurants" are meal vouchers provided by some employers, the employer pays part of it, and that part is free of taxes and social security contributions.


How is the cashless situation in Schengen, particularly the Northern and Eastern Europe countries, for American visitors using a US credit card? I heard Amex coverage is spotty but Visa/Mastercard coverage should be decent for those that accept it.

My experience in some of these countries is more limited than in others and I cannot comment on issues with US cards specifically but in general it is possible to go cashless pretty much everywhere in Northern, Western, and Central Europe. This include small transactions, street vendors, even buskers or prostitutes in some places (I kid you not!).
Amex coverage is indeed more limited, Visa and Mastercard are ubiquitous, the main issue is that in that in some countries (e.g. Germany, the Netherlands), there are shops that only accept local debit card and will refuse international credit card.
Since tipping culture is very different, you will find that the terminals and process is also different (no touch screen where you have to sign or enter the tip, no taking your card away and coming back with a receipt where you have to add the tip).

Also heard recommendations to add the credit card to Google/Apple Pay since EU uses pins for credit cards but US credit cards usually don't have them (and are Google/Apple Pay even prevalent enough to matter)?

Google/Apple pay are very common and actually seem to work with all bank card point-of-sale terminals that support contactless payments, which is almost all of them at this point. Using your card through one of these systems is excellent advice because it can take care of some issues with US cards programmed to favor PIN-less or chip-and-signature transactions.

"taking your card away and coming back with a receipt where you have to add the tip" that took a few goes to get used to when I visited the US. "You have to do what with my card now?". Prior to visiting the US, the card had either been in my wallet or in my sight for at least 10 years. Letting someone wander off with my $100-limit no-PIN contactless card Is Just Wrong!

(of course now I know that the reason it's OK really, is that approximately nobody in the US actually has a terminal that will make a signature-less, PINless charge).

Switzerland
I live in Switzerland (Zurich), and take cash out approximately once or twice a year. I use Apple Pay exclusively. I think the last place I saw that only took cash was some tiny restaurant nearly at the top of a mountain - presumably due to lack of internet connectivity; the restaurant 5 minutes walk further on did take cash.

This is also generally my experience as a tourist across different parts of Switzerland. I used no cash at all on my last trip there earlier this year. I never even got any francs on my last trip there.

Germany, big cities
Cards, in general
Contrary to other answers, in big cities (Munich, Hamburg, Berlin) I've rarely had to use cash in recent years, almost everywhere takes card. Last time I spent cash was 2 months ago for a taxi, as I was next to a taxi stand and wanted to test my German.
Grocery stores, bars, biergartens, many restaurants, government bureaus, corner shops (kiosk, späti, etc), hotels, many pharmacies, etc etc all take card in my experience.
I do have to say that I rarely dine outdoors, and when I do it's often international fast food or not-cheap restaurants (25-50eur/person). I do buy burritos and döner every now and then, and rarely needed cash. I've been told that my experiences on restaurants not needing cash aren't super representative by those that dine outside more, so you may need to carry some cash just in case. Places that take cards often list mastercard/visa logos on the door or near the ordering area.
Some places do only take EC-Karte (a local debit card type), but their numbers are dwindling and they often have huge signs saying things like "Nur EC-Karte" so you know to avoid them. In my experience, these have been mostly places aimed at locals: A small neighborhood pharmacy, for example. I've been living here for almost 3 years now without an EC-Karte, and have been making do just fine, you will too.
As a tourist, you may want to use luggage lockers at German train stations, which will often only take euro coins. You can check what they accept on the bahnhof.de website, some stations have card readers, but I haven't run into them yet.
For taxis, you can call regular taxis with Uber or freenow, and pay thru the app. Due to language barrier you probably want to do this anyways.
Some smaller stores (some ethnic stores, some döner shops, etc), alongside street markets etc are indeed unlikely to take card. That said, all the döner shops in my area take card, and I did pay with card at a döner shop in Gransee, which is a town with 6022 people.
One can absolutely pay for food delivery with card: Lieferando, Wolt, Uber Eats all let you order food and pay for it online, I never paid for delivery food on door in Germany, cash or card. Of course this locks you out of some options that only accept delivery orders by phonecalls, but language barrier would probably not make this appealing to a tourist anyways.
Amex
In my experience, amex acceptance is pretty good, but you shouldn't rely on it solely. Hotels, big grocery chains, public transport companies (esp. when buying thru the app), many restaurants, ikea, etc all take amex in my experience. Even used amex in a small Bavarian town's edeka once.
When I lived in Munich, I had months where I'd only need to spend maybe ~50EUR on my mastercard, and rest of my monthly expenses (1000+EUR) would go on my amex. It's a bit worse in Hamburg and Berlin, but it's still quite good.
For online purchases, it's accepted on Amazon, Lieferando, Uber Eats, eBay (thru paypal), etc.
For public transport, MVG of Munich, BVG of Berlin, HVV of Hamburg and Deutsche Bahn all take it for online ticket purchases too.
I'd say don't leave it at home, but don't count on it working everywhere. Presence of an amex sticker on the business isn't a guarantee, I was told before that "they hadn't activated it yet". If you want to only pay by amex, ask before you order.
Do note that amex often has unfavorable FX rates and FX fees. I never use my amex outside eurozone for this purpose, as my main mastercard has no FX fees and just passes mastercard rates through (which are often better than amex rates). If amex rates and fees are more favorable than rest of your cards, then by all means, give it a try.
Oh, and I just remembered that amex tried to advertise saying they have good acceptance a while back with this link: https://amex.de/akzeptanz, you could check the businesses listed there to get an idea, but it's not a conclusive list (most Rewes and Edekas also take amex, but they're not on that page).
Totally contactless
I've also been living the "totally contactless" lifestyle and haven't had issues. I wouldn't count on it everywhere, but I can't remember the last time I inserted my card into a POS machine.
Summary
In the big cities, I'd keep around the price of one taxi ride or one meal as cash (for me, I keep ~50eur, though as a tourist I'd keep at least 60eur*), and have around 10eur in coins for things like luggage lockers. If you run low, just obtain more, though I'd consider that unlikely.
*: In case you get a public transport fine (happens to tourists often), and choose to pay cash on the spot. I'd suggest this for a tourist, but insist on getting a receipt!

I live in Munich and always find it hard to believe or understand that it is claimed possible to cope without cash. Just this week, I've been in three situations where a card payment was not possible. A few days ago I bought a few crates of beer at a beverage shop and had to pay cash because only German bank cards were accepted. Today I had to pay cash to send a parcel (card payments only above 10€) and for a doner kebab at a place where cards are not accepted. I could waste much time, make substantial detours and restrict what I can buy by going elsewhere, but is it really worth it?

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo It's also down to lifestyle and preferences. The answer does acknowledge the döner kebab shop but if you like app-based deliveries or prefer international fast-food brands (I don't), you might never even have to think about it. Same thing for the parcel, the last time I sent one without a pre-paid pre-printed label must be several years ago, I just don't need it and I don't have to go out of my way to avoid it. Surely, for a visitor, all the things you mentioned are at most minor annoyances.

On balance, I think the answer provides enough information for the reader to make their own judgment and also does a good job of highlighting things that are especially relevant to visitors like the luggage lockers and taxis ; I upvoted it. Besides, getting cash in a foreign currency is not free either. I find looking for ATMs, figuring out which one might offer the best fees, and making sure I get the right amount of cash to be as much as a hassle as skipping a random beverage shop.

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo I guess one thing I can admit is that when I lived in Munich I didn't dine outdoors very often, relied more on ordering. That said, my neighborhood döner shop (not a posh one, but not a sketchy one either) does take card (mc/visa). I will clarify this in my answer. I tend to get my crates through flaschenpost, but the Getränkemarkts around me do also take card (but a tourist is unlikely to buy crates, if they do they'll prob use the supermarket ones). For parcels I buy the label online as it's cheaper. Lifestyle matters I guess.

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo: I really think that comes to lifestyle. Is a tourist going to "need" to buy several crates of beer at a beverage shop? I mean, they could save some money that way, but they'll live without. Likewise there's a restaurant I really like in the centre of Oxford UK that's cash only, but there's at least three restaurants I can think of in sight of its door, that take cards. So, if you want to get the best options of course you carry cash and at least two cards, but if you're willing to make do just make sure you know how to ask before you order!

@SteveJessop I was just listing the situations where I had to use cash during the last week and not trying to imply that these are typical tourist activities. Although buying a crate of cold beer at a store, bring it to a park and spend a nice and cheap evening there instead of going to an expensive pub is very likely not just something locals often do, but also tourists. And the 'not accepting foreign credit or debit cards' and 'minimum amount' problems are certainly not limited to beverage shops and parcel services.

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo: Right, I just mean that you came in quite strong with, "hard to understand that it is claimed possible to cope without cash". I think "cope" might be exactly the right word for what you can (and have to) do without cash :-) It's possible, it's just not very sensible. Even ave's "totally contactless lifestyle", still involves routinely carrying cash as a backup plan! That emergency cash is rarely used, but "rarely" ruining your holiday is still a risk.

Germany
It depends a bit on what you are going to do, but you cannot generally go cashless in Germany if you plan to:

Take a taxi.
Buy take-away food, in particular from small places run by people with a Middle East/North Africa cultural background (such as Döner places).
Buy at street markets or mobile vendors.
Pay for food delivery (might work if the restaurant is on lieferando, although tipping is still cash)

This is true even in big cities.
(I don't think Germany is either in Northern or Eastern Europe, but the question was tagged germany.)

"Pay for food delivery." I’m living in a village quite a bit away from a medium sized city and all local restaurants offering delivery take orders via lieferando, which has no problem with cashless.

@MisterMiyagi True, if they are on lieferando (which half the restaurants delivering to my place).

And unless I'm out-of-date or it's very cultural, most taxis will agree to take you via the nearest ATM. Assuming you're able to ask. So, cashless because you don't currently have any isn't as bad as cashless because you refuse on principle to use it.
